# How do you stop squid from despawning?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft how do you stop squids from despawning ***without name tags!***

Comment: @BillyMailman Not a dupe because I don't have any name tags

Comment: Then see all the other answers on that question. There's more than one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without nametags, you cannot stop squids despawning in vanilla Minecraft.

Comment: Except for going around it in circles and staring at it from less that 24 meters - if that suits you.